# Single value decomposition of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

Find a singular value decomposition for
$$X =
 \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 2 \\
    -1 & 1 \\
    2  & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$
So far I have found 
$$X^tX =
\begin{bmatrix}
    9  & -9 \\
    -9 & 9  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
with eigenvalues $λ = 18$ and $0$. I was then able to find $$u_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
    \tfrac23 \\ \tfrac13 \\ -\tfrac23
\end{bmatrix}$$
As the second eigenvalue is $0$, I then could not find $u_2$ and $u_3$ in order to work out $U\Sigma V$ and thus find the final answer.

How can I find $u_2$ and $u_3$ to complete the matrix $U$?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need $u_3$, you just need $u_2$, and just like you found $u_1$ as the vector that satisfies the equation $X^TXu_1 = \lambda_1 u_1$, you can find $u_2$ as the vector that satisfies the equation $X^TXu_2=\lambda_2 u_2$, where, of course, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the two singular values you found.

Comment: I found u1 = 1/sqrt(λ1).X.e1, as λ2 =0 I cannot divide by 0.

Comment: @Victor Your calculation of $u_1$ is incorrect, I suggest you re-read the chapters on singular value decompositions.

Comment: But I have checked my u1 calculation with a few different sources and it seems to be correct.

Comment: @Victor It is most certainly not true that $X\cdot e_1$ is always a singular vector of matrix $X$. I don't know where you got that idea.